# R function %^% not found even though dplyr is loaded

Tags: r, dplyr

I dont understand why this doesn't work.
I have the following matrix ma1

```
             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]         [,4]
[1,] 5.996807e-01 1.114280e-01 0.288891231 4.235966e-40
[2,] 4.405318e-26 9.200561e-01 0.079943925 2.926447e-98
[3,] 8.174676e-01 1.388150e-24 0.121288003 6.124443e-02
[4,] 8.145808e-02 3.090223e-22 0.002188103 9.163538e-01
```

and I am trying to do

```
ma1 %^% 100
```

but I am getting this error

```
Error in ma1 %^% 100 : could not find function "%^%"
```

even though I have loaded the library beforehand.

```
library(dplyr)
```

I have run this code after not looking at it for a long time, did something change in the R versions or libraries?
I think it worked in Version 3.0 perfectly (2019).

```
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I have never seen that pipe before.

Comment: Sure you don't mean ``%>%``?

Comment: @SamR I want the powers of matrices... I stumbled across a SO post saying dplyr library but I actually found out now its library(expm) that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(expm)
```

is the library to use for powers of matrices.